# How to convert SQL data to JSON in NextJS

Tags: sql, reactjs, json, codeigniter, next.js

I am making a web app using Codeigniter 4 and nextJS I am using a theme and in that theme, the  navbar has a dropdown menu that is getting mapped and the data is in JSON format so now I am also thinking of doing the same but I do not know how to convert SQL to JSON

```
"menu_1": [
            {
                "text": "Home",
                "url": "/",
                "extraClass": "menu-item-has-children",
                "subClass": "sub-menu",
                "subMenu": [
                    {
                        "text": "Marketplace Full Width",
                        "url": "/"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Home Auto Parts",
                        "url": "/home/auto-part"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Home Technology",
                        "url": "/home/technology"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Home Organic",
                        "url": "/home/organic"
                    }]
```

this is the JSON format and this is how it is getting mapped

```
const Menu = ({ source, className }) => {
    // Views
    let menuView;
    if (source) {
        menuView = source.map((item) => {
            if (item.subMenu) {
                return <MenuDropdown source={item} key={item.text} />;
            } else if (item.megaContent) {
                return <MegaMenu source={item} key={item.text} />;
            } else {
                return (
                    <li key={item.text}>
                        <Link href={item.url}>
                            <a>
                                {item.icon && <i className={item.icon}></i>}
                                {item.text}
                            </a>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                );
            }
        });
```

now I want to do the same using SQL, so is there any way to replicate something like this else it would be a hassle for me

Comment: fetch data from database and in PHP map your data same as above structure in associative array where each key same as above structure and than convert array data to JSON. first try with top level menu than go for sub menu.

Comment: can you give me some example code on how to do it? I have no idea how to do this .